# Custom MKClusterAnnotation failing on didSet

Tags: swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

Have a custom MKClusterAnnotation named 'ClusterAnnotationView.' It is failing at 'assertionFailure' message when I'm not expecting it.

Here is the code:

```
//MARK: CLUSTER ANNOTATION
final class ClusterAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    collisionMode = .circle
    displayPriority = .defaultHigh
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
    didSet { 
        guard let annotation = annotation as? MKClusterAnnotation else {
            print(annotation)
            assertionFailure("Using ClusterAnnotationView with wrong annotation type")
            return
        }
        self.image = image(count: annotation.memberAnnotations.count)
    }
}

private func image(count: Int) -> UIImage {
    let bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))

    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
    return renderer.image { _ in
        //background
        Definitions.Colors.Water.setFill()
        UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds).fill()

        // Fill inner circle with white color inset so background shows as border
        UIColor.white.setFill()
        UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds.insetBy(dx: 4, dy: 4)).fill()

        // Finally draw count text vertically and horizontally centered
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
            .font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        ]

        let text = "\(count)"
        let size = text.size(withAttributes: attributes)
        let origin = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX - size.width / 2, y: bounds.midY - size.height / 2)
        let rect = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)
        text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: attributes)
    }
}
}
```

Now if I comment out the 'assertionFailure("Using ClusterAnnotationView with wrong annotation type")' it'll shown the clustered annotations with the correct number. The print of  annotations all print nil.

Reviewed the docs on Apple on [Clustering](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkitjs/mapkit/annotations/clustering_annotations) and quite a few others. Many examples show it like I have it.

It's registered

```
mapView.register(ClusterAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
```

and the delegate for it is like so

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    switch annotation {
    case is MapAnnotation:
        let eventAnnotation = MapAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
        eventAnnotation.delegate = self
        return eventAnnotation
    case is MKClusterAnnotation:
        //return ClusterAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
        
        return mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier, for: annotation)
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

I've tried the return in the delegate with both the class and just the dequeue with same results.

Something odd is happening because the clustered annotations causes the maps functionality to be really laggy and it's possibly related to the problem I'm seeing.

Anyone have any insights?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one mistake in `func mapView`:

You need a different reuseIdentifier for each different `MKAnnotationView` subclass for which you are calling `mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView`.

What happens here is random:

if `return mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView` is called first, it returns nil.

nil means `mapView.register...` kicks in and creates a `ClusterAnnotationView` instance and everything works fine. That's when you see numbers.

It gets interesting once you created several `MapAnnotationView` and the first is thrown away when it isn't displayed any more:

Since you use the same `reuseIdentifier`,

```
return mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier, for: annotation)
```

will return an object of type `MapAnnotationView`.

Also, after using `dequeue...` you should set the annotation of the dequeued `MKMarkerAnnotaionView` subclass object.

This is the pattern you use for each different annotation type:

```
if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: ClusterAnnotationView.REUSEIDENTIFIER) as? TimeAnnotationView {
    dequeuedView.annotation = clusterAnnotation
    return dequeuedView
} else {
    let clusterAnnotationView = ClusterAnnotationView(annotation: timeAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: ClusterAnnotationView.REUSEIDENTIFIER)
            returnclusterAnnotationView
}
```

You might do a similar pattern for MapAnnotationView.

It is always the same: you try to dequeue. If it fails, you create a new one. For each different `MKMarkerAnnotaionView` subclass, you use a different `reuseIdentifier`.

Comment: It was my understanding from reading the docs that when you register an annotation it does what you describe per view (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/2887124-register)

Comment: viewFor annotation: overrides register.